# Почему серваки возвращают не «HTTP 408 (Request Timed Out)», а 200 и текст «Maximum execution time of xxx seconds exceeded», или еще какую чушь?

Tags: php, ajax, apache, timeout

Задача:
имеется REST API на PHP. В нем возможен баг (или просто тупизм сервака), хотелось бы, чтобы при запросах через jQuery, срабатывал "error" callback (для логирования и др.) а success callback не срабатывал.
А это будет происходить в таком случае только если ограничить timeout в самих AJAX Settings (т.е. на клиенте - а не на серваке), или если сервак вернет какую-то ошибку, например, 408.

Для тестов создал скрипт с бесконечным циклом.

На локалхосте (XAMPP) видимо execution limit стоит в 30 сек.
Сервак возвращает ответ с текстом "**Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded**", что само по себе не кстати (ответ должен быть в формате JSON, не надо его засорять), а главное - **возвращает 200, как будто все ок**. И как прикажете такое обрабатывать?

На хостинге видимо execution limit нету.
Сервак **возвращает ошибку 500** и текст про "**Internal Server Error**".
Это лучше, но опять не совсем то.

Почему везде так? 
Это так и должно быть, или это сугубо проблема Apache/nginx?
Что делать? Только задавать timeout на клиенте?

P.S. 
И вообще, что-то я не вижу, чтоб хоть какую из этих ошибок (ну кроме 404) какой-то сервак возвращал бы "из коробки".
Скажем, 500 тоже не используется при ошибках в PHP вроде деления на нуль. **Может настроить как можно, чтоб раз и навсегда? И главное - не bad ли это practice считается?**
Ну такие ошибки можно самому отловить, и вернуть их самому, либо как HTTP, либо в JSON как-то. А с этой что делать?

P.P.S.
Не стесняйтесь писать, что "пых уныл, вот у нас в Python\Ruby\ASP.NET... такого нет")))))
Но в первую очередь хотел бы ответа на вопрос в заголовке

Answer (score 1):

408 ошибка о другом:

```
10.4.9 408 Request Timeout

The client did not produce a request within the time that the server was prepared to wait. The client MAY repeat the request without modifications at any later time.
```

Более вероятно 504 Gateway Timeout и да, это зависит от настроек сервера приложений, а также прокси которые до него прокидывают - например бывают конфигурации когда режут количество соединений от одного клиента и т.д.

По существу в onsuccess проверять ответ, и от этого уже отталкиваться в отображении результата.